# Add all my EAV attributes to a product

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

So I am going thru Alan Storm's Magento tutorials and completed this page about EAV attributes. http://alanstorm.com/magento_advanced_orm_entity_attribute_value_part_1

It worked flawlessy, but I have a couple questions. I have an XML feed I am trying to read products from and storing in the DB. While this works, and they are added to the new table created, when I look in the admin under Manage-->Products, there are no products listed.

I also noticed in the admin when I go to catalog-->Manage Attributes, I don't see all the new EAV attributes. From his explanation, and looking at the new DB tables, I see where the actual product data & attribute meta data is being stored; in my newly created tables.

But I would like to:

1. See all these new products I am saving to the DB in the Manage Products in the admin
2. Make sure the new EAVs I added (based on the XML field names) are associated with these items when placed in the main admin product view

I followed his code exactly, just changed the names based on my experiment:

```
foreach ($xml as $c) {
        $car = Mage::getModel('vehicleimport/eavvehicle');
        ...
        ...
        ...
        $car->save();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If would like to use Magento products manager, then you should stick to the Magento core functionality. There are no products in `Catalog > Manage Products` because you do not use Mage_Catalog module and its entities to store those products.

Instead you are using your custom module. This is not a correct way to store your catalog.

It seems that you want to use some custom attributes on your products. That's fine and correct. But you need to add them to the `catalog_product` entity, not you're custom `eavvehicle`.

To add new product attribute go to the admin panel `Catalog > Manage Attributes` and create new one. There is a way to create them dynamically. Just use `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup` object, e.g.:

```
$catalogSetup = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/setup','default_setup');
$catalogSetup->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'attribute_name', array $attributeDefinition);
```

Or you can use your module to define the setup and then use upgrade scripts to add new attributes when they are needed.

You can define also attribute sets to group attributes. This allows you to put only necessary attributes on products.

You would like to use `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')` to add your products. So your loop would look like:

```
foreach ($xml as $c) {
        $car = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
        ...
        ...
        ...
        $car->save();
}
```

If you're using multiple store views (perhaps language versions) then you can set different language values for the same product. To save them for proper store you would need to set correct store view, e.g.:

```
$car = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$car->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore('french')->getId());
$car->setName('French Name of the car');
$car->save();
```

If you do not use multiple store views, then it is safe to set `admin` store id on product before save.

Mandatory fields/attributes for creating new product in Magento:

- attribute_set_id
- type_id (i.e. simple, configurable, grouped, etc.)
- website_ids (as array)
- is_active
- status (not sure if it's mandatory)
- visibility
- All attributes grouped in attribute set that are set as required (i.e. sku, name, price, tax_class_id, etc.)

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Magento is slowly starting to make sense. I start with learning their layout system, and now trying to move onto manipulating product data and how to display it all. I will give all of this a shot this weekend.

Comment: Hey I am getting an error on a invalid foreign key restraint when trying to save. All of my attributes have been added. Stepping thru the code, it dies when trying to add a row to `catalog_product_entity` table. The `attribute_set_id` field is missing. Do I need to assign the default attribute set somehow? I have seen this method `->setAttributeSetId(4);` but is there a global ENV type for default attribute set? I am guessing 4 was a PK in the example, but I don't want to hard code it like that.

Comment: Yes, the `attribute_set_id` is mandatory on when creating new product. All attribute sets are stored in `eav_attribute_set` table and can be viewed/edited in Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attribute Sets. You can use `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Set` model to load them by name, e.g. 'Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_set')->load('Default', 'name');` and then `$car->setAttributeSetId($attributeSet->getId());` I have update first post with other mandatory settings.